# parsing non-ASCII character in XML document

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, xml-parsing, sax

I'm trying to parse this XML document with a SAX parser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE WIN_TPBOUND_MESSAGES SYSTEM "tpbound_messages_v1.dtd">
<WIN_TPBOUND_MESSAGES>
    <SMSTOTP>
        <SOURCE_ADDR>+447522579247</SOURCE_ADDR>
        <TEXT>TEST: @£$¥èéùìò?ØøÅå&amp; ^{}\\[~]¡&#8364;ÆæßÉ!\"#¤%'()*+,-./0123456789:;&lt;=&gt;? ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà end</TEXT>
        <WINTRANSACTIONID>652193268</WINTRANSACTIONID>
    </SMSTOTP>
</WIN_TPBOUND_MESSAGES>
```

After parsing the `<TEXT>` element, the content is converted to:

```
TEST: @Â£$Â¥Ã¨Ã©Ã¹Ã¬Ã²?Ã�Ã¸Ã�Ã¥& ^{}\\[~]Â¡€Ã�Ã¦Ã�Ã�!\"#Â¤%'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>? Ã�Ã�Ã�Ã�Â§Â¿Ã¤Ã¶Ã±Ã¼Ã  end
```

So clearly something bad is happening to the non-ASCII characters. The code that parses the XML is shown below:

```
public void parse(InputStream xmlStream) throws WinGatewayException {
    XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
    parser.setContentHandler(this);
    parser.setErrorHandler(error);
    parser.setEntityResolver(new DTDResolver());
    parser.setDTDHandler(this);
    parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
    parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
    parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", true);
    parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", true);
    parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error", false);
    parser.parse(new InputSource(xmlStream));
}
```

and the object referred to by `this` has methods such as:

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equals("TEXT")) {   
            logger.debug("Parsed message text: " + cData.toString());
            message.setText(cData.toString());
        }
}
```

Why aren't these non-ASCII characters being preserved by the XML parser?

Comment: Depends what `xmlStream` is. Is it a `Reader` or an `InputStream`? Also, what is `cData`?

Comment: Please try enclosing non-ascii chars under CDATA section. [Chere here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

Comment: @artbristol I've updated the code to show that it's an `InputStream`

Comment: Are those characters *genuinely* ISO-8895-1 encoded? What are the bytes involved for the "£" sign for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your XML file is *actually* in UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-1.

An ISO-8859-1-encoded file would have a single byte per character, so the UK pound sign would be a single byte 0xA3. However, it looks like your file has 0xC2 0xA3, which is the byte sequence you'd get for U+00A3 in UTF-8.

Change the XML declaration to reflect this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and see if that fixes things. Assuming it does, you then need to work out what's produced this bad data to start with.

Comment: That's one possibility. Another possibility is that the input file is OK, and indeed that the data being logged is OK, but the content of the log is being displayed incorrectly: perhaps the log file contains UTF-8 characters, but is being displayed as if it contained iso-8859-1.

Comment: @MichaelKay: That's possible, but very unlikely given the input data. The chances of all those "Â" characters just *happening* to be part of useful UTF-8 characters is pretty small, I'd say.